# Freecodecamp Basic JavaScript: Nesting For LoopsPassed

Tags: javascript

I am having issue with this challenge, I keep getting a Reference Error on the product variable.

The question is:

**Modify function multiplyAll so that it returns the product of all the numbers in the sub-arrays of arr.**

```
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;
  // Only change code below this line
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0;j < arr[i].length;j++){
    product = product * arr[i][j];
  }
}
  // Only change code above this line
  return product;
}

multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(product);
```

I feel like my code is correct and product should equal 5040.

Comment: This is a very basic scope issue. `product` is only scoped inside the function. You could use another scoped version outside like `var product = multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);`

Answer (score 0):

Your function multiplyAll works fine. The problem is, your *product* variable is declared inside it, so you can't access from outside. If you want to print *multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);* result, you should put it on a console.log():

```
console.log(multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]));
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
function multiplyAll(arr) {
  var product = 1;
  // Only change code below this line
for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; i++){
  for (var j = 0;j < arr[i].length;j++){
    product = product * arr[i][j];
  }
}
  // Only change code above this line
  return product;
}

var prod=multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]);
console.log(prod);
```

**When you return someting from a function make sure, you save result inside a variable where you gonna call the function**

Answer (score 0):

you can simply do

```js
const multiplyAll = arr => arr.flat().reduce((a,c)=>a*c)

console.log( multiplyAll([[1,2],[3,4],[5,6,7]]) );
```

doc:
[Array.prototype.flat()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/flat)
[Array.prototype.reduce()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce)
https://schier.co/blog/method-chaining-in-javascript